# How to retrieve and display options from Drop down(developed using div tag)in Selenium WebDriver using java

Tags: selenium

I want to display all the options exist in `Div Drop` down.
I have tried many ways but no luck.
I can Select an Item in Div Drop Down using the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='listbox']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     Actions a=new Actions(driver);

 //I am going to Select 'March' option from drop down
 //by default the cursor is at October option...so i used keys Up for March


a.sendKeys(Keys.UP).build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(5000);?
     a.sendKeys("March").build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     a.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(10000);
```

---

The above code is perfectly working for me
But now i want display all the options from drop down
Please help in to this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your HTML code of the page.

Answer (score 0):

To display options you simply click on that dropdown :)

To retrive values from that dropdown use:

```
driver.findElements(By.locator("your_locator"))
```

This function returns list of elements found by given locator.

So if you want to retrive all options from the dropdown you need to find locator which points on all values from drop down list.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get all the options:

```
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='listbox']")));

    //Get all the options from dropdown
    List<WebElement> options = dropdown.getOptions();

    //To print all the option values
    for(WebElement option : options){
        System.out.println(option.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code

```
List<string> ddlText  =  CurrentDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@role='listbox']//div")).Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

Where "//*[@role='listbox']//div" is your DIV items of DDL.